in python using re.sub how do i interpolate text
I want to scan for the situation where a certain string 'INC0459444' is next to a date as in the following example
INC04594442024-06-05
If this is the case, I want to interpolate the text '\tnull\t' between the INC string and the date.  How to do that with re.sub?

use either lookarounds so the strings you're searching for are not part of the match, or use capture groups so you can copy them into the replacement string.

The linked question isn't an exact duplicate, but the principle is the same. If you think this question is distinct, you can [edit] to say so. (Think something along the lines of "I looked at [this question], and it covers how to match preceding text, but not following text. Here's what I tried that didn't work: ...")

If you are certain that the date will be in the YYYY-MM-DD format, you can make a regular expression that matches it.
import re

content = "INC04594442024-06-05"

pattern=r'(INC\d{7})(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})'

replace = r'\1\tnull\t\2'  # \1 and \2 are the capture group in parentheses

result = re.sub(pattern, replace, content)

print(result == 'INC0459444\tnull\t2024-06-05')  # True

